# How to solve PageSpeed Insights Diagnose performance issues for accessibility section getting question mark

Tags: accessibility, pagespeed-insights

When using PageSpeed Insights to test website performance, Accessibility scores are not displayed and are displayed as question marks and getting "Background and foreground colors have a sufficient contrast ratio Error!" this is happening for multiple page in a site

We tried to run Accessibility on Axe tool it was able to give results without error.
Expectation : Need to give Accessibility score

Comment: If I were to guess I think PageSpeed Insights might be having the [same issue as Lighthouse](https://twitter.com/bramus/status/1655504052518637569) in that when axe-core gives an incomplete result for color contrast that contains an error message (not a violation) it doesn't complete the audit and instead gives a question mark and the error you are getting. This happened recently when using new CSS4 colors that axe-core previously did not support.